# JavaScript - import/export & destructuring

Tags: javascript, object, module, redux, destructuring

Is there a way to combine these two export statements?

I understand that modules are not object literals, but it seems strange that I cannot actually import and then export actions here. From what I've tried so far, it appears that you have to export directly from an import.

And if no solutions are currently available, are there any future proposals on the horizon that anyone knows about?

```
// index.js

import reducer from './reducer';
import selectors from './selectors';

export * from './actions';
export { reducer as default, selectors };
```

**Update**

Since an explicit import/export doesn't appear to be possible, I decided to settle for consistency, making my selectors object a regular export as opposed to a default export, and then directly exporting from all three imports.

```
export * from './actions';
export * from './selectors';
export { reducer as default } from './reducer';
```

I'd still be interested in a solution for the original question, though.

Comment: Which of "these two statemenst" do you mean? And why can't you "import and then export actions here"?

Comment: @SebastianSebald The two export statements on the bottom. `actions.js` has many exports. I need to import all of those actions and then export them from `index.js`. Optimally, destructuring would work `export { reducer as default, selectors, ...actions };`, but apparently modules don't support destructuring.

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it! :)

Comment: so, your question is how to do it with one export statement? why? what is the benefit?

Comment: @JaromandaX benefit? brevity. why? curiosity.

Comment: fair enough - I was just wondering :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
export { reducer as default } from './reducer';
export * from './selectors';
export * from './actions';
```

Maybe not 100% what you want, but it's still one less line of code.

---

But you actually could do the destructuring with CJS. Something like this should work:

```
exports = {
  default: require('./reducer').reducer,
  selectors: require('./selectors'),
  ...require('./actions')
};
```

Comment: Lol, looks like we're on the same page — I just updated my question with almost exactly the same thing. I'll upvote you, though, if I don't get an answer to my original question in a few weeks.

Comment: Yeah ;) I guess TC39's current focus, when it comes to ES modules, is to make CJS and ESModules compatible. The current ESModule syntax has no destruction: http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html Though, CJS has!